# How to view all possible values between two columns of data

Tags: google-sheets

I have columns A, and B, and I want to divide every value in A by the values in B. For example, divide 15 by all values in column B, once done, shift down and divide 57 by all values in column B etc. Does anyone know how to do this?[image]

Comment: For starters, we'd need to know where you plan for this output to go (which would require a 2D grid with as many rows as you have values in Col A and as many columns as you have in Col B). Really, if you set up your posted Col-A values in a column (say, A2:A8) and your posted Col-B values across a row (say, B1:H1), you could get the results you want with a single formula in B2. We just don't have enough pieces yet to efficiently and effectively offer a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the dividends in column `A2:A10` and the divisors in `B2:B10`, put this in cell `C2`:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / (A2:A10 / transpose(B2:B10)) ^ -1 ) )`

Comment: that has a little error, try: <pre>
=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / A2:A10 * transpose(B2:B10) ) ^ -1 )
</pre>

Comment: I tested you answer and there is a problem. But @DANIELE noticed a misplaced closing bracket - I tested that correction and it is right. I've edited the answer to correct the closing bracket from "after" to "before" the exponential operator.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the missing parentheses in the canonical way.

Comment: @doubleunary the correct formula is `=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / A2:A10 * transpose(B2:B10) ) ^ -1 )` - there's only **one** closing bracket following the digit "-1". I think you edited my edit ;) Better that I hadn't done that at all. lol

Comment: @Tedinoz you are correct, but the problem is that when exponentiation is outside the `iferror()`, empty rows and zeros will get `+Infinity` and show `#NUM!`. Using parentheses in the canonical way also anticipates that readers may apply the pattern to a calculation that involves addition or subtraction.

Comment: @doubleunary Absolutely right. All my testing was with values in all cells.